# PHP - What regex code do I need to match this boundary sequence?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text string:

-asc100-17-asc100-17A-asc100-17BPH-asc100-17ASL

What regex code do I need to extract the values so that they appear in the matches array like this:

-asc100-17

-asc100-17A

-asc100-17BPH

-asc100-17ASL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Impossible to tell unless you describe a bit further the patter. Is -asc100-17 fixed? Can it be the exact same thing but for, say, -asc101-19?

Comment: Each value (a product code) will always starts with "-asc100" and I wanted to use regex to avoid having to use explode() and thereby strip out that part of the product code only to then have to add it back in again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very limited information in your question, this works:

```
-asc100-17[A-Z]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WK9EG_OoiFGGEBc5)

If you want to capture the post `-asc100-` code, then use

```
-asc100-(17[A-Z]*)
```

Which places `17[the letters]` into capture group one.

Comment: How does that work with PHP functions? I tried preg_match_all("/-asc100-17[A-Z]*/", $text_string, $matches) but it didn't match anything.

Comment: I just confirmed that the regex does work in PHP flavor (with the `g` option) in regex101: http://regex101.com/r/kP6dM0. I know regex, but I don't know PHP, so I'm afraid I won't be more help than that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$str = "-asc100-17-asc100-17A-asc100-17BPH-asc100-17ASL";
preg_match_all('/-asc\d+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+/', $str, $matches);

// Print Result
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -asc100-17
            [1] => -asc100-17A
            [2] => -asc100-17BPH
            [3] => -asc100-17ASL
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) as well for [your scenario](https://eval.in/127514):

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?=-asc)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Comment: Thank you - that works also. I hadn't thought about using preg_split() actually but I like how the array assignment works - with preg_match() it seems unintuitive to have to define the name of the array in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to break the string in an array? Then why regex is required? This function can handle what you want:

```
$arr = explode('-asc', '-asc100-17-asc100-17A-asc100-17BPH-asc100-17ASL');
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(!empty($value)){
        $final[] = '-asc'.$value;
    }
}
print_r($final);
```

Output array : **Array ( [0] => -asc100-17 [1] => -asc100-17A [2] => -asc100-17BPH [3] => -asc100-17ASL )**

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about using explode() but as I've mentioned in one of my other comments I didn't want the matching part of the value to be stripped out.

Comment: What about combining substr and strpos and looping to make the array:          $mys = '-asc100-17-asc100-17A-asc100-17BPH-asc100-17ASL';
        $f = '-asc';
        $arr[] =  substr($mys, 0, strpos($mys, $f, 1));
        $mys =  substr($mys, strpos($mys, $f, 1)); Check length of $mys and loop back .... If you get what I'm tying to say ...

Comment: Yes, I understand - that would work as well. Do you agree that using preg_match_all() or preg_split would be a simpler solution?